# Cannot mount Developer Disk Image for iOS 13.6 using libimobiledevice

Tags: ios, diskimage, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to use the functionality of libimobiledevice on my iPad to do stuff like change location (`idevicesetlocation`) and etc. I have no problems if I install the Developer Disk Image using XCode, but as a primarily PC user, I would like to be able to use my program solely from my own computer. After trying the command `ideviceimagemounter IMAGE_FILE IMAGE_SIGNATURE_FILE` and using the files from https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases for the two files, I get these messages:

```
Mounting...
Error: mount_image returned -3
```

I've tried this with multiple different file sources and two different iOS devices with the same result. Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I can clarify my question in any way, I've never really posted on here before. Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the full output of `ideviceimagemounter -d [image file] [signature file]`? This should dump the communication with the device, which will give a better idea of what went wrong.

Comment: If I add -d to the command, it prints the same thing in the command line. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of libimobiledevice do you have, and which operating system are you on?

Comment: Sorry, just realized I've actualy been using this: https://github.com/iFred09/libimobiledevice-windows

Comment: Perhaps try this version: https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/releases/tag/v1.3.6

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I've added an answer to summarize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of libimobiledevice. The libimobiledevice team from time to time updates the codebase to maintain compatibility with new versions of libimobiledevice.

If you're on Windows, you can try to use the binaries from the libimobiledevice-win32 project which I maintain. The latest release is available at https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/releases/tag/v1.3.6.